# iOS In-App Purchase Non-Consumable using Virtual Currency (Consumable)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've searched for this answer extensively but I cannot seem to find it despite the fact that this is seemingly common practice.

I want to create an app where the user purchases coins/credits/tokens (virtual currency) and they can then redeem that virtual currency for an actual non-consumable good. This is very important to me. I understand that consumable goods are not synced across devices or backed up and that's fine, but what they purchase absolutely needs to be synced across devices and backed up.

So how do I purchase a non-consumable using a consumable such as virtual currency?!

Comment: It sounds like the non-consumable would not have an additional price (past the consumable currency). Is there a particular reason you have to represent the non-consumable with Apple mechanisms? Or could you just "fake" it with your own mechanism?

Comment: As I said, non-consumables are automatically synced across devices and restorable automatically through apple's mechanisms. I need that functionality and really don't want to have to reinvent the wheel and support servers.